# Looking for a RegEx Find and Replace Visual Studio addons

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2008, add-in, replace

I am looking for a Visual Studio Addon which does standard Regular Expression Find and Replace, not the [Microsoft Visual Studio version of Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

As you do not get the [complete syntax](http://knol.google.com/k/brian-lalonde/microsoft-visual-studio-special-regular/34l0bem1ht3yo/3#)

Please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always write a VB.Net macro to do this; depending on how flexible you want it to be.

For Find and Replace on the current document, you could use this simple script - ALT+F11 to fire up the macro editor and then away you go.  Paste this sub into a new Module:

```
Sub RegexReplace()
    Dim regex As String = InputBox("Enter regex for text to find")
    Dim replace As String = InputBox("Enter replacement pattern")

    Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Dim editPoint As EnvDTE.EditPoint

    selection.StartOfDocument()
    selection.EndOfDocument(True)

    DTE.UndoContext.Open("Custom regex replace")
    Try
        Dim content As String = selection.Text
        Dim result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, regex, replace)
        selection.Delete()
        selection.Collapse()
        Dim ed As EditPoint = selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint()
        ed.Insert(result)
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        DTE.UndoContext.Close()
        DTE.StatusBar.Text = "Regex Find/Replace complete"
    End Try

End Sub
```

Save the module, go back to VS and open the 'Macro Explorer'; navigate to the macro and double-click it to run (sorry if you know all this - just trying to be thorough!).  You can later assign a keyboard shortcut to this macro too.

Obviously if you want all the functionality that the existing find/replace dialog provides then you have to do more work; and might be put off by that.

The most obvious enhancement to this code (apart from proper error handling!) would be to build a form on the fly with all the input boxes you need rather than displaying successive input boxes!

Just an idea ;)

Answer (score 5):

This one works with Visual Studio 2008 and uses the .Net Regex syntax: [.NET Regular Expressions Find and Replace Add-In for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VS2008RegexAddIn.aspx).

Comment: Sweet! just used a positive lookbehind: (?<=^\s*\[OperationContract.*\(.*\]\s*$\n).* to find the next line after an [OperationContract] WCF attribute!  (visual studio regex does not support this)

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look here: [The Visual Studio IDE and Regular Expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html)

> There's a free [add-in available](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/searcheraddin.aspx) which offers real regular expression searching in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Rubens,I am aware of the link you provided, the syntax link I provided show the syntax that is not available, which is why I am looking for the add-in.

Unfortunately the Add-in you provided is for Visual Studio 2003.